# Laravel eloquent interval 10 +

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, intervals

My question is about  the interval i cant get it to work.

```
$totalCount = $datamodel->select('*')
            ->where('country', 'like', $selectionfield)
            ->whereBetween('MEASUREDTIME', [$begindatum, $einddatum])
            ->where('gpsvalid', '=', 1)
            -->whereRaw('receivedtime<=(MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)')
            ->get();
```

> Error Code : 907 Error Message : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   Position : 195 Statement : select * from (select * from people where
>   "COUNTRY" like :p0 and "MEASUREDTIME" between :p1 and :p2 and
>   "GPSVALID" = :p3 and receivedtime<=(MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10
>   MINUTE)) where rownum = 1 Bindings : [NL,2017-08-01
>   00:00:00,2017-08-03 00:00:00,1] (SQL: select * from (select * from
>   people where "COUNTRY" like NL and "MEASUREDTIME" between 2017-08-01
>   00:00:00 and 2017-08-03 00:00:00 and "GPSVALID" = 1 and
>   receivedtime<=(MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)) where rownum = 1)

Comment: Is Laravel throwing an error? If so can you include the error dump?

Answer (score 1):

Yuo need to use raw queries for this .laravel has  `whereRaw` method

```
     $totalCount = $datamodel->select('*')
                    ->where('country', 'like', $selectionfield)
                    ->whereBetween('MEASUREDTIME', [$begindatum, $einddatum])
                    ->where('gpsvalid', '=', 1)

                   ->where('receivedtime', '<=', DB::raw('MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE'))
                    ->get();
```

Comment: if my updated answer giving error then try ->where('receivedtime', '<=', DB::raw('MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)')

Comment: We are getting somewhere error now says Error Message : ORA-00904: "(MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)": invalid identifier
Position : 170

Comment: can you try this .->where('receivedtime', '<=', DB::raw('MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)')

Comment: ->whereRaw('receivedtime', '<=', DB::raw('MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE'))                                                                                           gives this error illegal variable name/number

Comment: and the ->where gives missing right parenthesis again

Comment: can you replace to ->where('receivedtime', '<=', DB::raw('MEASUREDTIME + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE')) this should work

Comment: gives error Error Message : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis